# Related Rates/Differentiation

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

A spherical snowball is melting in such a way that its volume is decreasing at a rate of $1~\frac{\text{cm}^3}{\text{min}}$. At what rate is the diameter decreasing when the diameter is $10~\text{cm}$?

I got $1/100 \space (3.14)~\frac{\text{cm}}{\text{min}}$ as my final answer.
Please help me!

Thank-you for your time!

Comment: Can you also show us how you got your answer? That way, we can check for errors...

Comment: $\frac1{100\pi}$ you mean?  I think you're on the right track, except I think that might be the rate the radius is decreasing.

Comment: Your answer should be $\frac{dr}{dt} = -\frac{1}{100\pi}~\frac{\text{cm}}{\text{min}}$ since $\frac{dV}{dt} = -1~\frac{\text{cm}^3}{\text{min}}$ since the volume of the snowball is decreasing.